# Upgrade keeps asking for updates to 19.10 before 20.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

I was notified today May 9 that 20.04 was available, so I clicked upgrade and it hung. After a reboot, I got the dreaded Partial Upgrade box, then I just tried a command line do-release-upgrade. That told me to install updates first, which I did with sudo apt-get update and upgrade, but running do-release-upgrade again loops me through the update prompt again.
Will I ever be able to upgrade to 20.04?  If so, how?

Comment: Do it manually with a bootable USB.

Comment: You could follow the route in this resource: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-ubuntu-19-10-to-ubuntu-20-04